# Criteria to distinguish permutations from the other bijective (&etc.) maps on binary sequences

Tags: permutations

A follow-up to [MSE4856267](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856267/21498), some context is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931619/625396).

Consider binary (0/1) sequences of length $n$. Permutations (symmetric group $S_n$ ) act on any sequences - just permuting the symbols. Moreover there are obvious orbits - sequences containing precisely $k$ symbols $1$ - are orbits for any $k$.

That action satisfies the following obvious properties: it is bijective and the sequence with $k$ symbols $1$ are mapped again to the sequence with such property.

However not any map satisfying the properties above is induced by permutations - for example $NOT$ is not induced - see [MSE4856267](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856267/21498)

**Question:** is there any criteria which distinguishes permutation induced maps from the other ? What can be the algorithm to find such permutation if we have is description as MAP (i.e. pairs of input/output) on the sequences of length $n$ containing precisely $k$ symbols $1$ ?